# What are the default options that rsync uses if you pass none to it?

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, rsync

For example, I can do `rsync --delete --archive --links --perms --etc source_dir final_dir` and I know which options I'm using. What if I do just `rsync source_dir final_dir`? What are the defaults?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From manpage:

> Rsync  finds  files  that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.  Any changes in the other preserved attributes (as requested by options) are  made on the destination file directly when the quick check indicates that the file’s data does not need to be updated.

Howewer, when you just call `rsync 1/ 2/` w/o any options (such as `-a`), nothing happens

Comment: Could you provide an example using all possible options that would be equivalent to `rsync -a 1/ 2/`?

Comment: I guess that's all we have to go by. Thanks.

Comment: @trusktr from the manpage again:

    `-a, --archive    archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`